# VPN Certificate expired - how can I rectify this?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2016

I have become the de facto IT/sys admin at my company for the time being.

We use Microsoft Server 2016 to manage our VPN connection.

I believe our certificates have expired.  No one is able to get onto the VPN and the error they get is "a required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the system clock or the timestamp in the signed file".

The old IT was kind enough to point me in the right direction.  He told me I will have to create a new certificate on the Microsoft Server computer that manages our VPN and then each client will also need a new certificate as well.

I have confirmed that our certificate on the VPN server did expire yesterday - [image]

I can provide more details if asked - I have access to the Server 2016 computer, but I don't know what is pertinent here.  What should my next steps be here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 4. The Issued by says ourcopmpanyname-VPN-CA. Old IT guy said it was self-signing I don't know if that means anything here. 5) I am able to run certsrv.msc and I do see the certificate there yes.

This means the certificate was issued locally through AD Certificate Services. You should be able to either renew it or request a new one directly through the usual "Certificates" panel (`certlm.msc`).

(It is *not exactly* "self-signed"; having your own internal CA is in the middle between "self-signed" and "public CA issued". Unlike true self-signed certificates, you don't need to reconfigure clients to recognize the new cert as they'll usually recognize your whole internal CA.)

In most cases it doesn't matter whether you keep the key or use a new one; what matters is the certificate profile (which influences what attributes will be set) and the domain name specified within the "Subject" (as clients will usually expect it to match what they're connecting to, like in TLS).

SSTP uses standard TLS certificates, however, so you *could* in theory also use a generic (public CA) TLS certificate as long as it's issued for the correct domain name. (PPTP normally doesn't use certificates at all; though a certificate *may* be involved if EAP-PEAP authentication is active, but that's set up on the RADIUS/NPS server, not on the PPTP server.)

The `certsrv.msc` console is the administration tool for AD Certificate Services and is usually not needed for issuance; in this case it just reveals that you do in fact have ADCS set up on the network.

Comment: There is little difference between requesting a new certificate and renewing a certificate, the end result is identical, a new certificate is created. You will have to put the Subject Name and Alternate Names that the original certificate had.

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak - View the certificate in the Certificate Store on the machine, which you already did, but the information you require is in the Details tab.

Comment: I was missing the CN.  So it was like CN=vpnob.mycompanyname.com and that worked!  Thank you all very much.