# New router cut off access to our application server?

Tags: networking, router, dns

I'm a inexperienced defacto interim IT person for my company, same as from this post [VPN Certificate expired - how can I rectify this?](https://superuser.com/questions/1791633/vpn-certificate-expired-how-can-i-rectify-this/1793370#1793370)

Today (well really yesterday evening) our optimum internet went completely out.  All my tests pointed to it being the modem, Optimum came out, agreed, and replaced the modem like for like, an ARGIS.  This goes right into a RV340 Cisco router.  They have set the moden to the same static IP that the prior one had.

Now access to a application server we have on bare metal in our closet and normally accessible via the internet is no longer accessible via the internet(nor is our VPN but I am trying to solve one thing at a time).  Luckily was able to set people up to use it locally but it's still an issue.

I ran a `tracert myapp.com` and I see the first hop is the CISCO router via the local IP, the second hop is the CISCO router's external IP, and then I get a `Destination host unavailable`.  I've restarted the CISCO router and the Microsoft Server 2016 VM we have that manages our VPN and our DNS via Server Manager.  I have no idea what to look at next.

I have the login for the CISCO router and am clicking around looking for something but I don't know exactly what I am looking for.  I also have access to the Microsoft Server 2016 VM.  I did see this on the Server 2016 DNS tab of Server Manager -
[image]

I don't know what else I should be looking at.  If you tell me I can look it up as I do have access to pretty much everything.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

From the CISCO router Page -
[image]

There are two external ip addresses listed there and both are pingable so I assume that the router is or does have an external IP?  But again I am not an expert.  I don't know if these IP's reflect the modem's IP.  When I try to go to either of these IP's in my browser it takes me to the CISCO router web interface.

EDIT 2:  The ex-IT person graciously responded to me.  He said all he had to do was open a few ports on the router to allow for the application server and VPN to work. I believe this means port 80 for the application server and port 443
/1723 for our VPN.

Comment: Sounds like your modem isn’t (just) a modem but a router.

Comment: I have used an Arris Modem (Hitron now) and have a Cisco RV340 router. Was the prior setup set to bridge modem in the modem?  Check that.  Do a reset on the Cisco RV30 and make sure it is set for DHCP for the WAN connection. Make sure the modem port selected is correct (usually number 1) That should help.

Comment: Normally a router only shows up as a _single_ hop – the 2nd hop with "Cisco public IP address" is most likely not the Cisco but the modem (also a router). What does the interface configuration on the Cisco router look like; does it _actually_ have the public IP address configured on it? What _kind_ of modem is it – cable modem (ARRIS) or some other technology? Do you still have the old modem? (I'm guessing it was either configured in "pass-through/bridge" mode or had an all-encompassing DMZ/portforward rule.)

Comment: @John Hi, the modem is plugged into the right hand WAN port and and a cable from the left hand WAN port of the CISCO router goes back into the modem - is this what you mean by bridge the modem in the modem?   After it was replaced Optimum called, had me reset the modem and the router and only after that did the internet start to work.  But our VPN and the application server became unusable.  I will have to wait to reset it again until tomorrow morning unfortunately people here are doing a lot of work right before leaving.   I'm not sure if the optimum tech put them back in the same order.

Comment: I wonder if you had a port-forwarding to the Microsoft Server defined on the old modem that is missing in the new one. Which box is the DHCP server here : The modem or router?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Hi - I added a picture and some context, the second hop to myapp.com matches the IP under WAN2 don't know if that means anything.  It is an Arris TG1672.  Unfortunately the optimum tech took the old modem with him so I cannot check it but it was the same model.

Comment: The cisco router will need to know how to send external traffic to the internal servers - that's usually a port forwarding rule. Is that a public IP on VPNOB? That would be a little different

Comment: @Cpt.Whale The left hand side of the IPv4 column in that Microsft Server pic an public IP address of which I don't know what it is - it is not the router as I get to that with two different IP's (listed in the second pic but blacked out).  It is the IP address that we use for our VPN connection actually.  So not sure that it is related to the application server issue though our VPN is down as well right now.

Comment: Please note my comment above about a possibly port-forwarding rule to the Microsoft Server which was previously defined on the old modem but that is now missing in the new modem.

Comment: @harrymc The last IT guy got back to me.  He said that in the router firewall he had to open a few ports.  However normally you do that through optimum.net and right now that section of the website is down for maintenance and unusable lol.  So I don't know what else to do at this point until that is usable.

Comment: Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @harrymc My old IT guy said we need to do some modem configuration but the optimum page is "down for maintenance" - apparently just for this business though.  My personal optimum account still has that page working.  I suspect its down because they just swapped our broken modem with a new one but from what I understand this